# Django cant connect to redis in docker

Tags: django, docker, task, celery

Sorry for my english. I have project in django, In my project i want use celery for background task and now i need set settings in docker for this library. This my docker file:

```
FROM python:3

MAINTAINER Alex2

RUN apt-get update

# Install wkhtmltopdf
RUN curl -L#o wk.tar.xz https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz \
    && tar xf wk.tar.xz \
    && cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin \
    && cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin \
    && rm wk.tar.xz \
    && rm -r wkhtmltox

RUN apt-get install -y cron

# for celery
ENV APP_USER user
ENV APP_ROOT /src

RUN groupadd -r ${APP_USER} \
    && useradd -r -m \
    --home-dir ${APP_ROOT} \
    -s /usr/sbin/nologin \
    -g ${APP_USER} ${APP_USER}


# create directory for application source code
RUN mkdir -p /usr/django/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/django/app/

WORKDIR /usr/django/app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

this my `docker-compose.dev`

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: api_dev
    image: img/api_dev
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/django/app/
      - ./static:/static
    expose:
      - "8001"
    env_file: env/dev.env
    command: bash django_run.sh

  nginx:
    build: nginx
    container_name: ng_dev
    image: img/ng_dev
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/dev_api.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/api.conf
      - .:/usr/django/app/
      - ./static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
    links:
      - web:web

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: pq01
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: rd01
    command: redis-server
    ports:
     - "8004:8004"

  celery:
    build: .
    container_name: cl01
    command: celery worker --app=myapp.celery
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/django/app/
    links:
      - db
      - redis
```

and i have this error:

```
cl01      | User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0
cl01      | 
cl01      |   uid=uid, euid=euid, gid=gid, egid=egid,
cl01      | [2018-07-31 16:40:00,207: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://redis:8004/0: Error 111 connecting to redis:8004. Connection refused..
cl01      | Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
cl01      | 
cl01      | [2018-07-31 16:40:02,211: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://redis:8004/0: Error 111 connecting to redis:8004. Connection refused..
cl01      | Trying again in 4.00 seconds...
cl01      | 
cl01      | [2018-07-31 16:40:06,217: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://redis:8004/0: Error 111 connecting to redis:8004. Connection refused..
cl01      | Trying again in 6.00 seconds...
```

i cant understand why it not connect. My settings file project

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:8004/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:8004/0'
```

Everything looks like good, but mayby in some file i dont add some settings. Please help me solve this problem

Comment: Are you sure that the redis is running on port **8004**?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge in my `docker-compose.dev` i set port redis `ports:
     - "8004:8004"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the port mapping causes the problem, So, change **`redis`** settings in `docker-compose.dev` file as (*removed `ports` option*)

```
redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: rd01
    command: redis-server
```

and in your `settings.py`

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
```

You dont have to map the ports unless you are using them in your local envirnment

Comment: thanks for answer. But when i set port `6379` i have error `ERROR: for redis  Cannot start service redis: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint rd01 (0b881a6f5a52d4bc815eeeba532e9589689a1d13abacc2e19f327914f1d48582): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:6379: bind: address already in use`

Comment: Updated the port mapping...try now

Comment: i have same error `[2018-07-31 17:43:02,630: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://redis:6378/0: Error 111 connecting to redis:6378. Connection refused..
cl01      | Trying again in 2.00 seconds...`

Comment: On this path the port mapping is ignored and the internal port is used.  That is, you don’t need a `ports:` block unless you want to access the Redis from outside Docker space, and within Docker space you should connect to `redis:6379`.